# Does a LEO mission to study the marine debris exist or is at least planned?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, environment

Would a mission to LEO to study and record the amount of marine debris be of use or is someone already doing it?

Comment: Welcome to space stack exchange! This site works on a model of accepting questions with right or wrong answers, not opinion-based or discussion type answers.  This means that your question is most likely going to be closed.  If you can reword it to be a better fit for this site, please do so.

Comment: I think the question is not an opinion or discussion, if such a mission exists or is at least planned, is an objective fact.

Comment: What marine debris are you talking about? Shipwrecks? Plastic soup?

Comment: Plastic soup @Hobbes

Comment: Plastic soup is microscopic plastic particles, density is 5 particles/m^3. That would make it difficult to detect from space.

Comment: This is the sort of thing I'm thinking about [link](https://www.google.co.uk/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fgreennews.ie%2Fwp3%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F09%2Focean-pollution.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fgreennews.ie%2Fcan-turn-tide-marine-plastic-pollution%2F&docid=4ljHcWGet0jy_M&tbnid=sHCXUTo9h9qbxM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjT0sHO3JHdAhUQbcAKHafFCGsQMwibAigLMAs..i&w=580&h=300&safe=off&bih=983&biw=1920&q=marine%20plastic%20pollution&ved=0ahUKEwjT0sHO3JHdAhUQbcAKHafFCGsQMwibAigLMAs&iact=mrc&uact=8)

Comment: @Hobbes wouldn't it refract light differently than plain water?

Comment: at 5 particles/m^3, that difference would be tiny. and refraction would only be affected if the particles are at the surface, which they aren't.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the European Space Agency is planning to do it, see this recent article (19 March 2018):

https://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Preparing_for_the_Future/Discovery/ESA_investigating_detection_of_floating_plastic_litter_from_orbit

> The millions of tonnes of plastic ending up in the oceans every year
> are a global challenge. ESA is responding by looking at the detection
> of marine plastic litter from space, potentially charting its highest
> concentrations and understanding the gigantic scale of the problem.
> [...]
>
> “What we are now looking at in this new project is to assess the
> feasibility of direct optical measurement of seaborne plastic waste
> from satellites. This might sound like mission impossible, but there
> are reasons to believe it might be indeed doable, at least for certain
> concentrations.
> [...]
>
> In particular, plastic has specific infrared fingerprints that are
> sometimes used in the recycling industry to sort plastic items from
> other refuse on a conveyor belt.”
> [...]
>
> Satellite images from missions such the Copernicus Sentinels are
> being checked against aerial coverage plus ground surveys where
> drifting plastic is collected from the sea to be assessed in close-up.
> Initial results were presented last week at the International Marine
> Debris Conference in San Diego, USA.
> [...]
>
> Paolo adds, “We hope to get an idea of what kind of concentration of
> marine litter is viewable from the top of the atmosphere using current
> technology, or if we’d have to operate from the middle of the
> atmosphere using aircraft or drones. Or would we have to improve the
> technology?
> [...]
>
> The project will deliver a preliminary set of requirements for a
> satellite to detect marine plastic litter in the shortwave infrared.

Comment: Good answer! To complement - a dedicated satellite could be too expensivee for this purpose. So more probable is a one of instruments on multipurpose satellite, or ISS plug-in instrument. Or microsat/cubesats if the payload could be fit in this scale.